# The result is not fixed after setting random seed in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, random-seed

```
def setup_seed(seed):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    random.seed(seed)
    torch.manual_seed(seed)  # cpu
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)  
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True  
    torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True
```

I set random seed when run the code, but I can not get fixed result with pytorch. Besides, I use **batchnorm** in my code. When evaluate and test, I have set **model.eval()**. I cannot figure out the reason for that.

Answer (score 4):

I think the line `torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True` causing the problem. It enables the **cudnn auto-tuner** to find the best **algorithm** to use. For example, **convolution** can be implemented using one of [these](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/1848cad10802db9fa0aa066d9de195958120d863/aten/src/ATen/native/cudnn/Conv.cpp#L486-L494) algorithms:

```
     CUDNN_CONVOLUTION_FWD_ALGO_GEMM,
     CUDNN_CONVOLUTION_FWD_ALGO_FFT,
     CUDNN_CONVOLUTION_FWD_ALGO_FFT_TILING,
     CUDNN_CONVOLUTION_FWD_ALGO_IMPLICIT_GEMM,
     CUDNN_CONVOLUTION_FWD_ALGO_IMPLICIT_PRECOMP_GEMM,
     CUDNN_CONVOLUTION_FWD_ALGO_DIRECT,
     CUDNN_CONVOLUTION_FWD_ALGO_WINOGRAD,
     CUDNN_CONVOLUTION_FWD_ALGO_WINOGRAD_NONFUSED,
```

There are several **algorithms without reproducibility guarantees**.

So use `torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False` for deterministic outputs(this may slow execution time).

And also there are some pytorch functions which cannot be deterministic refer [this](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html) doc.

Comment: +1 As indicated in the [pytorch docs on reproducibility](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html) `torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark` should be set to `False`.

Comment: Oh, thanks! But i still cannot get fixed result after setting `torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark=Flase`, I test on `CPU` and `GPU`. Is there anything wrong for batchnorm?

Comment: @Yan Tijin there are some pytorch backend functions which cannot be deterministic if some of them r used by your code(in backed)(some pooling, padding, sampling techniques use them). Then it may be the reason. Refer [this](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html)